# Why " print readdir(DIR_HANDLE); " will pop out many files?

Tags: perl

I use `readdir(DIR)` to read a file , but when I use

```
$file = readdir(DIR);
print $file;
print "\n";
sleep(2);
```

it will print a file one time;

but when I use

```
print readdir(DIR);
print "\n";
sleep(2);
```

it pop out many files

what's wrong with it?

thanks

Comment: read about list vs scalar context.  In print you are using a list.

Comment: So readdir can output list and single scalar?

Comment: As others have said, the behavior of `readdir` is different in list or scalar context, as do many other functions.  The understanding of the difference is crucial to success in learning Perl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`readdir` does not read a file.  It scans a directory for the next directory listing.

You can check out the `perldoc` for it here: [readdir](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readdir.html)

The reason it printed only one file with your declaration of `$file` is because it is a scalar value.  It will only read from the directory handle once and return a listing.

More commonly when you want to read from an entire directory, you assign it to a list which is what `readdir` returns thus printing all the directory listings in your second example.

Answer (score 0):

`readdir` returns the next file when evaluated in scalar context (or undef after the last one has been read).

```
my $file = readdir($fh);
```

The scalar assign operator evaluates its RHS operand in scalar context.

---

`readdir` returns the remaining files when evaluated in list context.

```
my @files = readdir($fh);
```

`print` evaluate its argument list in list context.